# Postgres SQL GROUP BY depending on a value from another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case, having-clause

I am trying to query set result set which returns something like the below.
I need to return only 1 row per name and need to GROUP BY but only the name that have a value of '8' under the Grade column are desired. The below is a result from another query. Because Sandra has a different value other than 8, Sandra should be omitted.

eg:- In the below I need to get one row for John only.
Please advise. Thank you.

```
    Name      Grade
    =======   =====
    Sandra     8  
    Sandra     8
    Sandra     8
    Sandra     9
    John       8
    John       8
    John       8
    John       8


    Expected Result - 1 row

    Name     Grade
    John      8
```

Comment: Can you show us your desired output?  It's not clear whether what you showed us is the input or output.

Comment: Name Grade
       John      8

Comment: Just edited and added to the code section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate your table on the name, and then use a `HAVING` clause to filter out names which have a grade other than 8 (or any other values which you do not want).

```
SELECT name, MIN(grade) AS grade
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN grade <> 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

### Demo

**Update:**

If the `grade` column were text, and you wanted to compare against the string `'8'` instead of a number, then you could use this `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN grade <> '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! I need to group by name and filter out any names which might have rows with any other value than 8. And 8 is only dummy data.

Comment: @StackoverflowUser I updated my answer.  Your original question was not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Il try this out and update the results, Thank you Tim

Comment: @StackoverflowUser Yes, the logic would work.  You would just need to change to checking for a string literal instead of a number.  Let me update now.

Comment: Used the DEMO, Thank you Tim!

Answer (score 1):

If you want names that have only 8s, you can do:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having min(grade) = max(grade) and min(grade) = 8;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, the 8 is only dummy data and the min and max functions cannot be used in my actual data.

Comment: Really simple and what I needed but hadn't considered this myself yet today. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately,

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.name, B.grade
FROM
(
    SELECT name FROM yourTable GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT grade) = 1
) Z
INNER JOIN
yourTable B
ON Z.name = B.name
AND B.grade = 8;
```